# I have a long string "AAAAA...". How to find the shortest pattern "A"?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I have a very long string "AAAAA..." and it is necessary to find the shortest possible pattern A. Do you have any suggestions? I know how to do it in brute force, but what is the optimized way?

UPDATE:
an example:

`S=absabsabsRabsabsabsRabsabsabsR`

the answer is `A=absabsabsR`. Once again the `A` in `S` is an unknown pattern, which should be determined in linear time(`O(n)`).

Comment: Are you saying you have a string x and you want to find the shortest string y such that x = y^n (n copies of y all concatenated with each other) for some n >= 1?

Comment: can you give an example? if your string is ```AAAAA...``` and you are looking for the shortest pattern ```A```....well, it's ```A```....? pls elaborate, your question is unclear

Comment: Show code. Noone here is writing code for you. If you know how to "brute force" it show your brute forcing code and we can tell you what your inefficiencies are.

Comment: As a tip. If your string is "ABCABCABCABCABC..." you may find a pattern e.g. "ABCABC". If your pattern has a pattern then it is not the shortest possible pattern. Simultanously a pattern of your pattern is still a pattern of your test string.

Comment: I am sorry for not giving an example... I have updated

Comment: what is the brute force approach you seek to optimize?

Comment: "the answer is absabsabsR" Okay, what is the rule that tells you this? How would you solve the problem by hand?

Comment: Using `Z-function` we can get this efficiently in `O(n)` https://cp-algorithms.com/string/z-function.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in linear time by building the Knuth-Morris-Pratt state machine for the string.  That will tell you all the suffixes of the string that are also prefixes.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

For each such suffix, the remaining prefix is a divisor of the string if `len(remainder)` divides `len(suffix)`

Answer (score 1):

this should work...not in linear time though (see comment) :-(

```
text = "absabsabsRabsabsabsRabsabsabsRabsabsabsR"

# any repeating sub-pattern must match the entire string and fit exactly n times
# len(text) = len(pattern) * n
# there is always worst case solution: the text contains itself exactly once.
pattern = text
# for shorter patterns we can stop after patterns exceed length len(text) // 2. any pattern longer than that can only
# be the text itself...
for n in range(1, len(text)//2+1):
    # also len(text) must be integer divisible by n. so we don't need to test all patterns of length n, but only those
    # that satisfy len(text) % n == 0. if this is case, the pattern, if repeated len(text)//n times, must be equal to
    # the given text...
    if len(text) % n == 0 and (text[0:n] * (len(text) // n)) == text:
        pattern = text[0:n]
        break  # abort on first/shortest found...
print(pattern)
```

generates:

```
absabsabsR
```

Comment: Hi, mrxra! Thank you for your help! I tried your solution and I found out that there is it seems that your function doesn't work if pattern == text)

Comment: ...not sure I understand...if ```pattern``` == ```text``` then no shorter sub-pattern exists. e.g. if ```text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"``` then the shortest repeating sub-pattern matching ```text``` is ```"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"``` (with no. of repetitions = 1), this solution always exists....unless there is a shorter one.

Comment: This is **quadratic** algorithm, not linear, so look at more effective alternatives like Photon comment, Matt answer

Comment: oops...I guess you are referring to the hidden loop ```text[0:n] * (len(text) // n)``` ?

Comment: Both making string in this code and comparing it with `text` has complexity n, and together with outer loop count n/2 we have O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

You mean **[the longest repeated substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem)** without overlapping, like [the longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), but in the same string, not between two strings.

in your example you find the longest repeated substring, not the shortest one. because, yes if is is the shortest pattern it will be 'a' or any other repeated alphabet.

To find the longest repeated pattern we use suffix tree (suffix array...). you can look at the [**related question here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem) where you can find source code and suggestion to different implementations.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having different variable with different length of string? if so, follow this step
example:

```
a = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
b = 'aaa'
c = 'aaaaaaaaa'
print(min(a,b,c))
```

Comment: Hi MrVang, The long 'AAAAA' string is a given but the pattern is not known.

Comment: @MrVang, welcome to SO. It is preferred to ask clarification questions in comments.